# Ubuntu RAM clock speed, help!

Tags: uefi, ram, bios, clock

I have 2400 MHz memory, but Ubuntu runs it at 2133 MHz. I enabled xmp profile in the UEFI, and now when I use the command `sudo dmidecode --type memory`, it shows Speed: 2133 MT/s and Configured Clock Speed: 2400 MT/s. Which one is right?

- CPU: Pentium g4560 (Kaby Lake 7h gen)
- mobo: ASRock LGA 1151 B250M-HDV (it supports DDR4 2400 if using 7th gen CPUs)

Using the command `sudo lshw -short -C memory` it's showing "8GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2133 M".

In the UEFI it's saying I'm using 2400MHz. I'm confused now.

Comment: Some motherboards are limited to specific speeds for RAM operation, even though the CPU would support faster. Suggest you click [edit] and advise the motherboard make and model, if the make and model of the PC. Please don't use Add Comment, but instead click [edit].

Comment: This `sudo lshw -short -C memory` would give you the right one. Also please bare in mind as @K7AAY mentioned that different CPU, motherboard and chip-set configurations or overclocking as well as one memory module VS upgrading by adding another memory module  may alter the working memory speed stated by the factory.